# Show posts between two Custom Fields date

Tags: posts, wp-query, post-meta

I'm trying to fetch all the posts from today to next week by using some custom fields inside posts, using Advanced Custom Fields.

Everything was working until now, because it doesn't show posts from the next month.
For example:

I've got posts whose 'date' custom field is `'28/01/2015'` or `'29/01/2015'` or `'30/01/2015'` and everything is working.

But I've got some posts which 'date' is `'01/02/2015'` and `'02/02/2015'` and they're not showing at all.

In ACF I've set the 'date' custom field as a jQuery Datepicker, which show dates in `dd/mm/yy` format and save them also as `dd/mm/yy`.

This is my code:

```
                $t=date('d/m/Y',strtotime('+7 day'));
                $o=date('d/m/Y',strtotime('today'));

                $d=new WP_Query(
                    array(
                        'category__in' => array(4),
                        'post_type' => 'post',
                        'posts_per_page' => '-1',
                        'orderby' => 'meta_value',
                        'order' => 'ASC',
                        'meta_query' => array(
                            'relation' => 'AND'
                            array(
                                'key' => 'data',
                                'value' => $o,
                                'compare' => '>='
                            ),
                            array(
                                'key' => 'data',
                                'value' => $t,
                                'compare' => '<'
                            )
                        )
                    )
                );
```

Can someone help? Thanks in advice.

Comment: You are going to have a tough time doing this. Your date format is wrong. It should be `YYYY-MM-DD`.

Comment: So are you saying that the only problem is the date format inside database? Is everything fine inside the code?

Comment: On eye value, it looks fine.

Comment: Ok, better than expected, if the only problem is date format, it's not an enormous problem by the way